# Multi-dimensional array and pointer to pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

When you create the multi-dimensional array `char a[10][10]`, according to my book it says you must use a parameter similar to `char a[][10]` to pass the array to a function.

Why must you specify the length as such? Aren't you just passing a double pointer to being with, and doesn't that double pointer already point to allocated memory? So why couldn't the parameter be `char **a`? Are you reallocating any new memory by supplying the second 10.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Pointers are not arrays**

A dereferenced `char **` is an object of type `char *`.

A dereferenced `char (*)[10]` is an object of type `char [10]`.

**Arrays are not pointers**

See the [c-faq entry about this very subject](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

---

Assume you have

```
char **pp;
char (*pa)[10];
```

and, for the sake of argument, both point to the same place: 0x420000.

```
pp == 0x420000; /* true */
(pp + 1) == 0x420000 + sizeof(char*); /* true */

pa == 0x420000; /* true */
(pa + 1) == 0x420000 + sizeof(char[10]); /* true */

(pp + 1) != (pa + 1) /* true (very very likely true) */
```

and this is why the argument cannot be of type `char**`. Also `char**` and `char (*)[10]` are not compatible types, so the types of arguments (the decayed array) must match the parameters (the type in the function prototype)

Comment: Also that link you provided is awesome.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you like the c-faq. Don't read just section 6: read [all of it](http://c-faq.com/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

C language standard, draft [n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> ...
> 3  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator or the unary `&` operator, or is a
> string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is
> converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points to the initial element of
> the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the
> behavior is undefined.

Given a declaration of

```
char a[10][10];
```

the type of the array expression `a` is "10-element array of 10-element array of `char`". Per the rule above, that gets coverted to type "pointer to 10-element array of `char`", or `char (*)[10]`.

Remember that in the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are identical to `T *a`; thus, `T a[][10]` is identical to `T (*a)[10]`.